# I wondered what proof exist for the existence of gravitons?

Tags: quantum-gravity

It seems from my perspective that gravity is an indirect trait of matter; meaning that gravity is a trait of spacetime itself and that when matter interacts with spacetime, a bend occurs producing gravity.  The question I wonder is that we have proven gravitational waves, since particles are evoked by topological changes in spacetime, would gravitons also be an evoked particle, producing the effects we see.

Comment: Absolutely none.

Comment: Possibles duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119254/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10088/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52211/2451 , and links therein.

Comment: There is quite rigorous proof for the existence of gravitons. It's just that there exists an ad hoc rule that is not based on physics, that a particle can only be "officially" detected in traditional experiments (bubble chambers etc.) and that is just not going to happen for gravitons. However, if you write down a theory where gravity is classical then this will necessarily be in conflict with so many things that it is immediately falsified. So, in that sense, the non-existence of gravitons can be said to have been experimentally falsified.

Comment: @CountIblis: General relativity isn't in conflict with a single observed phenomenon and nobody has been able to even formulate a self-consistent quantum theory for gravity. Gravitons are, even on the theoretical level, nothing but intellectual nonsense at this point.

Comment: @CountIblis "However, if you write down a theory where gravity is classical then this will necessarily be in conflict with so many things that it is immediately falsified."       ... and what about frame dragging, gravitational time dilation, cosmology in general..oh and that whole gravitational wave detection thing which was also able to yield detailed data regarding the bodies that made it? I wouldn't say GR has been immediately falsified!