# Existence of the Graviton

Tags: quantum-gravity, carrier-particles

The PDG http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/html/authors_2018.html lists the [Graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) as an observable particle (measurements).  Is this an accepted fact? All other information says it is just hypothetical i.e. Wiki etc.  see  http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-sum-gauge-higgs-bosons.pdf

Comment: The first link appears to just be a list of people, and the second link just notes an upper bound on the mass that a graviton could have if it existed.  Am I missing the part that says that it's been observed?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119254/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It has not been observed, and may never be.

Comment: Have you [asked the PDG site what their intention is](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/contact.html) ?  We cannot be certain what their intention is and they *may* need to clarify their pages.

Comment: [The PDF of the second link](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-sum-gauge-higgs-bosons.pdf) reports $m_\text{graviton} < 6 \cdot {10}^{-32} \, \mathrm{eV}, $ which [this PDF](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/rpp2018-list-graviton.pdf) reports as coming from [this 2002 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0204161).  Looks like it's sort of an old, speculative upper bound on a hypothetical graviton mass, rather than any sort of confirmation.

Comment: @Nat  By "observable" I am using their reported measurement as the standard.

Comment: @Harry It's not really a "_measurement_" in the sense that I suspect you're thinking about.