# Which predictions can a theory of quantum gravity make - update since 2014?

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity

I have read the answers and comments to [What predictions can a quantum gravity theory make?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123155/what-predictions-can-a-quantum-gravity-theory-make) and I wonder if anything new can be added since 2014. Today we have an image of the Einstein shadow of the black hole in M87* produced by EHT and the discovery of gravitational waves by LIGO.

Comment: If you think the answers to an old question need to be updated, please offer a bounty instead of duplicating the question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind 2014 is a long time ago. I am satisfied with the answers to the 2014 question so I consider it closed. "The questions are the same but the answers are different " Einstein is supposed to have said once. That applies here. I am after the 2019 answers.

Comment: @ACuriousMind “Student: Dr. Einstein, Aren't these the same questions as last year's [physics] final exam?

Dr. Einstein: Yes; But this year the answers are different.” 

https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/226558-student-dr-einstein-aren-t-these-the-same-questions-as-last