# Does the existence of graviton contradict gravity being spacetime curvature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, spacetime, quantum-gravity, carrier-particles

Is gravity a property-curvature of space-time it's self as descriped in GR?

Or the notion of 'graviton' is necessary in order  to embed the 'classical GR theory' to the quantum's mechanics 'world' because it is considered more fundamental?

Or they can be both valid as well, because there's no such contradiction?

Comment: Possibles duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10088/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52211/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the reasons to expect that gravity should be quantized?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980/)

Comment: The usual motivator is the great success of quantum field theory, so one might expect the quantization of the gravitational field results in a gravitational particle. There are alternative theories, though, such as gravity being an emergent phenomenon.

Comment: @Qmechanic I would say that those questions are not exactly duplicates of this one as here the stress is on the particle nature

Comment: The existence of graviton doesn't actually contradict gravity being spacetime curvature

Comment: @OON , i could not 'defend' my question better! Please try to explain in more detail if you can! Your prelude is very interesting!

Comment: Whether you call it a particle or a wave is up to you since nomenclature is not important for physics, but verifiable predictions are. We now know that it does exhibit wavelike behavior from the recent detection of gravitational waves (just like light is an electromagnetic wave). A consistent low energy effective (quantum) theory of GR is perfectly fine and makes good predictions. But experimentally observing individual gravitons interacting with matter is (very) hard because gravity is very weakly coupled to matter.

Comment: Well, I'm just with a phone right now anyway and already spent my patience writing last. answer:P if your question will be reopened in a couple of days I'll write the answer

Comment: @aK1974 I suggest you rephrase your question a bit to emphasize the difference with questions referenced

Comment: Ok, i just rephrased the question, after @OON suggestion in his comment