# Relevance of non-quantized relativistic string theory

Tags: string-theory

Is there any relevance of it? E.g. some problems are easier to solve without quantization and correspondence makes it a valid solution.

This isn't about the quantization of gravity. It is much more general.

Comment: Possibles duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52211/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10088/2451 and links therein.

Comment: No, they aren't.

Comment: the context of AdS/CFT there has been some use of classical relativistic strings to say things about gauge theories at large N. 

For example https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0204051