# Why can't we use expected values for a "quantum general relativity"?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, qft-in-curved-spacetime

So, the equations for general relativity are as follows:
$$G (mu, nu) = ĸ T (mu,nu)$$
I was told, that since energy, momentum and other observables are quantum then the stress-energy tensor $T$ is quantum, and therefore the Einstein tensor $G$ must be adapted to it. However, what if we used expected values $\langle T\rangle$ to make the stress-energy tensor "classical" which makes quantum gravity "unnecessary". How would this lead to any problems, and why haven't we tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52211/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10088/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Using expectation value for T doesn't make quantum gravity unnecessary. $G=8\pi \langle T \rangle$ means that only the matter field is quantized on a classical background space time. It's called the semi classical approximation