# Relativity and QM

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity

According to general relativity, gravity is the result of a bending of spacetime.
So, why do we need to integrate the "force" of gravity into the standard model with gravitons?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/744057/