Can we define a quantum mechanical system on top of a classical GR spacetime?
I've heard my entire life that QM and GR are incompatible, but I don't exactly understand how. There are other questions about that general question, e.g. A list of inconveniences between quantum mechanics and (general) relativity?
But just to ask a more specific question: Is it possible to define spacetime according to einstein's field equations, and then just define a wave function for a set of particles on that curved spacetime, as you would in relativistic QM? I.e. don't try to "quantize gravity" or anything. Just define QM on a curved spacetime background.

Does this work? If not, where does it fail? If it doesn't work for quantum fields, does it at least work for a fixed set of quantum particles?

Is the issue that the curvature has to evolve over time, which makes it hard to solve?

If it's hard to solve, can we at least run numerical simulations (in principle, ignore computational intractability).

Or is it even fundamentally unclear how to mathematize this?



I'm not an expert in quantum field theory but I'm pretty sure this is almost exactly what is done - for example, Hawking radiation is derived by considering QFT on the known solution to spacetime around a black hole. You couldn't have these particles then influencing spacetime directly without quantising it, but I suppose you could have spacetime obey the expectation value of the stress-energy tensor.

You can always have a QFT on a curved spacetime. Refer to locally covariant QFTs. The incompatibility you mention is not exactly that bad and in principle one can have effective notions of quantum gravity. So -1 since there isn't an exact "problem" that is being asked.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10088/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52211/2451 and links therein.

Does this answer your question? Does "QFT in curved spacetime" combine QFT and general relativity?

In short, the "incompatibility" arises not when one conskders QFTs in curved space, but rather when one attempts to treat space itself as a quantum fielf.

@Vaibhavk, lol you're downvoting my question because it's based on a misconception I have because I'm not a physicist?

@paulina You got it right. GR is a theory of spacetime and QM of matter. The former is an immaterial continuum, it cannot be quantized like discrete matter. The desire for QGR comes from the idea that the gravitational singularity problem can only be solved with the help of quantum theory because of the measurement limits at Planck scale.

@user56834 I am not downvoting because you are not a physicist, but because this question has been asked with the same vagueness before. Why should that be strange? That is why moderation in Stackexchange exists, because there are thousands of questions being asked there is bound to be repetitions.

@user56834 I wouldn't (and didn't) downvote just because a question is a duplicate. However note that a downvote is not a personal criticism, although I must admit it often feels that way to me when I get downvoted. Anyhow a downvote just means the question is not considered suitable for the site and should not be taken personally.
