# What´s the physical foundation of the assumption that the curvature of spacetime can be quantised?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, quantum-gravity, curvature, quantization

At the moment different paths (by percentual very few people in the world) are taken to arrive (that is, *if* an arrival exists) at a theory that can quantise the curvature of spacetime. Considering the three basic forces that operate *in* spacetime I can imagine them to be quantized (and which obviously has been done in the three gauge field theories of those forces) *in* spacetime, but what is the argument that says that also the curved spacetime itself is subject to quantization?

It is clear that a curved spacetime, wich lets masses (in the absence of the e.m. strong- and weak force) interact without acceleration (in the sense of a force), is very different from the stuff out off which the workings of three real basic forces are made.

The search is on for many years now, but a solution hasn´t emerged. Can this be a sign of a wild goose chase or is the assumption an axiom, in which case there is nothing left to be answered?

Comment: If you are talking of quantization of  gravity, string theories have it. http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/magazine/physicstoday/article/68/11/10.1063/PT.3.2980

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What are the reasons to expect that gravity should be quantized?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980/)

Comment: Physics is an experimental discipline. Theoretical methods can only make reasonable predictions that are fairly close to already observed phenomena. You can rest assured that shortly after the first measurements have been made that show that spacetime is quantized, a reasonable theoretical model will emerge. I wouldn't expect that to happen in our lifetimes, though, our experimental techniques are simply not advanced enough.