# Is there any empirical evidence for the existence of the graviton?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-gravity, carrier-particles

In the standard model of particle physics, there are four fundamental forces/interactions, each governed or conveyed by its respective fundamental particle:

Strong force: quark/gluons

Weak force: neutron

Electromagnetism: Photon

Is gravitation hence subject to the existence of an analogous fundamental particle, the hypothetical graviton? If so, what, if any, empirical evidence suggests it exists?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton): “Unambiguous detection of individual gravitons, though not prohibited by any fundamental law, is impossible with any physically reasonable detector.”

Comment: *Strong force: quark/gluons Weak force: neutron* Quarks don’t carry the strong force, and neutrons don’t carry the weak force.

Comment: The graviton is implied if gravity is quantized .https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980/ Have a look at the question and answers here

Comment: A quantum is the irreversible exchange of a small small amount of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges. While this is well defined in the limit of flat spacetime, it is not completely obvious what it means in gravitating systems. I would not bet much money on it that gravity is "quantized" in the same way as the other forces are, hence the straight forward extrapolation of the "quantum" concept may be difficult if not outright meaningless for gravity. The difficulties with developing theories of quantum gravity back this up. And, no, gravitons have for sure not been observed.